# Moq NHiberNate ISession.Get doesn't call mock session object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nunit, moq

I am new to NHibernate and even newer to MOQ (or other similar frameworks). After searching online day and night (google + stackoverflow + others), I am turning here for help.

The scenario is (should be) simple. I am trying to unit test a call on a C# WCF service that uses NHibernate as the ORM layer. The method, after doing some initial work, finds a database to connect to, and then calls on the SessionProvider (a manager of session factories) to return a nhibernate session for a sharded DB.  I am then trying to use ISession.Get<>() to retrieve an object from the database aand then do some work. The problem is that the GUID (the key for the entry that I am looking up in the db) is generated at the begining of the call and I have no way of knowing what it might be beforehand outside the scope of the WCF call. Hence, I cannot use sqllite or other techniques to pre-populate the necessary data to control the test. What I was hoping for was that I can somehow mock (inject a fake layer to?) the call to Session.Get to return an invalid object which should cause the WCF call to throw.

Here's the test code snippet:

```
var testRequest = ... (request DTO)
var dummyBadObject = ... (entity in DB)

var mock = new Mock<ISession>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mock.Setup(m => m.Get<SampleObject>(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(dummyBadObject);

var exception = Assert.Throws<FaultException>(() => applicationService.SomeMethod(testRequest));
Assert.AreEqual(exception.Code.ToString(), SystemErrorFault.Code.ToString());
```

When I run this test, instead of interacting with the mock ISession object, the app service code calls the Get on the actual ISession object from the session factory, connects to the database and gets the right object. Seems like I am missing something very basic about mocks or injection. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: You have setup a mock ISession. But where are you registering that in SessionProvider?

Comment: The SessionProvider is part of the application service assembly, which when initialized, initializes the static session provider which in turn creates the session factory cache that hands out the sessions on demand. Because of this, I can't register the mock session directly without creating a test method on the application service that does the work internally for me. I was hoping that Moq could do a "global" intercept for ISession and hand out the mock session instead. Now this is where I can be totally wrong in my understanding of what Moq does. Perhaps Microsoft Fakes may be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments, the problem is that mocks are completely different from how you thought of them.

They don't magically intercept creations of classes derived from an interface. They are just dynamic implementations of it.

Creating a `Mock<ISession>` is not much different from creating a class that implements `ISession`. You still have to inject it in the services that depend on it.

You'll probably have to review your whole stack, as the capability to do this depends on a good decoupled design.

Suggested read: [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have a good bit of reading to do which is great.

Answer (score 0):

I re-designed the components in my application to have a ServiceContext object which in turns holds all the other (what used to be static) components that the application uses. In this case, this would be the session provider (or the ISessionFactory cache), and similarly a WCF channel factory cache. The difference is that the ServiceContext provides methods to override the default instances of the different components allowing me to replace them with mock ones for testing and restoring the original ones when testing is done. This has allowed me to create a test where I mock all the way from the session cache to the ISession.Get/Save/Load etc.

```
var mockDatabaseSessionFactory = new Mock<DatabaseSessionManager>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var mockSession = new Mock<ISession>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var mockTransaction = new Mock<ITransaction>(MockBehavior.Strict);

mockDatabaseSessionFactory.Setup(x => x.GetIndividualMapDbSession()).Returns(mockSession.Object);
mockDatabaseSessionFactory.Setup(x => x.GetIndividualDbSession(It.IsAny<UInt32>())).Returns(mockSession.Object);
mockDatabaseSessionFactory.Setup(x => x.Dispose());
mockSession.Setup(x => x.BeginTransaction()).Returns(mockTransaction.Object);
mockSession.Setup(x => x.Dispose());
mockTransaction.Setup(x => x.Commit());
mockTransaction.Setup(x => x.Dispose());

// Setups to allow for the map insertion/deletion to pass
mockSession.Setup(x => x.Get<IndividualMap>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((IndividualMap)null);
mockSession.Setup(x => x.Load<IndividualMap>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((IndividualMap)null);
mockSession.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<IndividualMap>())).Returns(new object());
mockSession.Setup(x => x.Delete(It.IsAny<IndividualMap>()));

// Our test condition for this test: throw on attempt to save individual
mockSession.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<Individual>()))
    .Throws(new FaultException(ForcedTestFault.Reason, ForcedTestFault.Code));

// Test it - but be sure to back up the previous database session factory
var originalDbSessionFactory = ServiceContext.DatabaseSessionManager;
ServiceContext.OverrideDatabaseSessionManager(mockDatabaseSessionFactory.Object);
try
{
    var exception = Assert.Throws<FaultException>(() => applicationService.AddIndividual(addIndividualRequest));
    Assert.IsTrue(ForcedTestFault.Code.Name.Equals(exception.Code.Name));
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Restore the original database session factory before rethrowing
    ServiceContext.OverrideDatabaseSessionManager(originalDbSessionFactory);
    throw;
}

ServiceContext.OverrideDatabaseSessionManager(originalDbSessionFactory);
ServiceContext.CommunicationManager.CloseChannel(applicationService);
```

Luckily the code design wasn't too bad o_O :) so i re-factored this bit easily and now code coverage is at 100! Thanks Diego for nudging me in the right direction.